# Unable to resolve react-bootstrap modules flow error

Tags: javascript, reactjs, flowtype, typechecking

I am setting up flow static type checking for my react project (pretty new to it). I also installed react UI library, [React-Bootstrap](https://react-bootstrap.github.io/).

This is how my current setup is:

**.flowconfig**

```
[ignore]
.*/build/.*
.*/node_modules/.*
.*/node_modules/npm.*
.*/node_modules/.*/node_modules/.*
.*\.test\.js


[include]
./src 

[libs]

[lints]

[options]
react.runtime=automatic

[strict]
```

**App.js**

```
//@flow

import React, { useState } from 'react';

import Container from 'react-bootstrap/Container';
import Button from 'react-bootstrap/Button';
import Alert from 'react-bootstrap/Alert';

import type { Node } from 'react';

const AlertDismissibleExample = (): Node => {
  const [show, setShow] = useState(false);

  if (show) {
    return (
      <Alert variant="danger" onClose={() => setShow(false)} dismissible>
        <Alert.Heading>
          I am an alert of type <span className="dangerText">danger</span>! But
          my color is Teal!
        </Alert.Heading>
        <p>
          By the way the button you just clicked is an{' '}
          <span className="infoText">Info</span> button but is using the color
          Tomato. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit.
          Accusantium debitis deleniti distinctio impedit officia reprehenderit
          suscipit voluptatibus. Earum, nam necessitatibus!
        </p>
      </Alert>
    );
  }
  return (
    <Button variant="info" onClick={() => setShow(true)}>
      Show Custom Styled Alert
    </Button>
  );
}

const App = () => (
  <Container className="p-3">
    <Container className="pb-1 p-5 mb-4 bg-light rounded-3">
      <h1 className="header">Welcome To React-Bootstrap</h1>
      <AlertDismissibleExample />
    </Container>
  </Container>
);

export default App;
```

There are 2 issues to my code that are related to flow:

**Issue 1. As I try to import the required react-bootstrap modules into my `.js` file, flow is throwing errors:**

Following are the errors I receive on the react-bootstrap modules I've imported in my App.js file:

```
Cannot resolve module `react-bootstrap/Container`.Flow(cannot-resolve-module)

Cannot resolve module `react-bootstrap/Button`.Flow(cannot-resolve-module)
```

and more...

---

**Issue 2. 'import type' declarations can only be used in TypeScript files.**

The statement ***import type { Node } from 'react';*** throws this error. I am unable to use flow-type for my functional components. I've all the proper VS-CODE settings to enable type-checking for .js files:

[image]

I tried to look around for the issues, but being new to using flow, I am stuck a bit. Any help to resolve the same (with some justification), would be really appreciated.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

Your issue is that you have flow setup to ignore all code from `node_modules`, see your `.flowconfig` line of code that goes `.*/node_modules/.*`.

This isn't necessarily wrong, it's what I would have done also but what that means is that when you try to import from `react-boostrap` flow will tell you it doesn't exist (hence `cannot-resolve-module`). But the reason people do this is because they want to improve flow's parsing speed with less modules to parse because their flow resolutions instead come from [flow-typed](https://github.com/flow-typed/flow-typed) (https://flow-typed.github.io/flow-typed/#/).

If you follow the docs you've eventually be told to run `flow-typed install` which will install definitions for libraries you have installed in your package.json, one of those will be `react-bootstrap` though important to note that it will be a stubbed package because it hasn't been typed by anyone in the community (you could be that person though) but it will solve your problems in the way your expect.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation! Although I got your point, but still a bit confused. The first being, if I remove the `/node_modules/`. from `.flowconfig`, it will resolve my 'cannot resolve-module' error, but then would it be heavy on flow, as it will also check unrequited node-modules? Second, what's the difference between flow-typed and flow?

Comment: "Would it be heavy on flow": In earlier versions yes it would, these days I personally am not feeling it so it's up to you, you can if you start seeing performance issues. "what's the difference between flow-typed and flow": `flow` is the static analysis tool that does all the type checking, whereas `flow-typed` is the third party definition registry that stores and add type checking for third party libraries that aren't written in flow themselves. `flow-typed` compliments `flow` and if you had no dependencies you wouldn't even need `flow-typed`

Comment: Ohkay, got it. Thanks! I'll try it out and see if it works for me.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure why you are importing Node from react but you can import like this

```
import { Container, Alert, Button } from "react-bootstrap";
```

Comment: I tried that too. Flow is unable to resolve installed packages. Got an error in this also: `Cannot resolve module 'react-bootstrap'.Flow(cannot-resolve-module)`

Comment: remove .flow if it doesnot solve problem i think you have mistakely changed .pacakages  or modules so try reinstalling your modules or try creating new project

Comment: Removing the flow isn't the solution. I need to implement it for type-checking. Also, I tried re-installing all the new packages to a new project, but that didn't help.